# sql table: sum up over intervals of 10 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a solution for my statistical problem:

I have a table with one date column in it. Now what I want to do is count the number of rows in a certain time interval of 10 seconds:

SELECT count(id), ... AS interval WHERE ... GROUP BY interval

Anybody an idea how I can perform this?

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected results.  Your question is not nearly as unambiguous as you may think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  CONCATENATE(
   SUBSTR(
    DATE_FORMAT(yourtimestamp, '%Y%m%d%H%i%s')
    , 1, -1)
   , 0) AS time_bin,
  COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable
WHERE ...
GROUP BY CONCATENATE(
   SUBSTR(
    DATE_FORMAT(yourtimestamp, '%Y%m%d%H%i%s')
    , 1, -1)
   , 0)
```

(use str_to_date() to convert back to a timestamp)
or...

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(
    10*FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(yourtimestamp)/10)
) AS time_bin,
COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable
WHERE ...
GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(
    10*FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(yourtimestamp)/10)
)
```

Comment: I'll leave it to you to work out why these give different results ;)